# seekBar set progress throwing null pointer exception

Tags: android

I am using a seekBar for zoom control of a custom camera app.  My app at times removes the cameraPreview and upon re- adding the cameraPreview i want to reset the progress of my seek bar.

```
public void restartCam() {

        //zoomCtrl.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(0x00000000);
        camPreview = new CamSurfaceView(this.getApplicationContext(), camFace);
        frame.addView(camPreview);
        zoomCtrl.setProgress(0);
    }
```

but i get a null pointer:

```
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.view.CamSurfaceView.zoomTo(CamSurfaceView.java:120)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CustomCamera.onProgressChanged(CustomCamera.java:643)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:670)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:651)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CustomCamera.restartCam(CustomCamera.java:568)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CustomCamera.cameraOn(CustomCamera.java:435)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CustomCamera$5.onClick(CustomCamera.java:317)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3558)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14157)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-03 12:18:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my on progress change:

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mode.equals("camera")) {
            camPreview.zoomTo(progress);
        }

    }
```

Comment: post your onProgressChanged, since it is where it crashes ...

Comment: just did and realized that the camera is not ready yet.. problem solved.. thannks

Comment: so just post it as a answer and accept it..or remove the question.

Comment: stack won't let me post an answer yet

Answer (score 0):

```
   Please, try this.

    if (zoomCtrl!= null) {
        zoomCtrl.setProgress(0);
    }
```